# Check if variable has value and isn't empty

Tags: php, variables

I want to check if a numeric variable has a value (**including '0'**) and is not empty. Empty meaning EMPTY (''), not '0'.

Is this really the best I can do with PHP?

```
if (isset($variable) && $variable !== '') { ... }
```

I'd like to do this with one check without writing a function for it...

Comment: `$variable != ' '` replace it.

Comment: `isset($variable) AND !empty($variable) AND !is_numeric($variable) AND $variable !== false`

Comment: @JeesKDenny Check the manual for `empty()` a zero is considered empty, that I assume is whole the point of the question

Comment: The first one works, !empty alone does not, because "0" counts as empty.

Comment: Edited. Very thanks I checked. @RiggsFolly

Comment: @D.Joe You could write a custom function for this kind of test,and then re-use it as u want

Comment: Yep, I'll call the function... empty() ;-)

Comment: @D.Joe What about `my_kind_of_empty()`

Comment: *"I want to check if a variable has a value (including '0') and is not empty. Empty meaning EMPTY (''), not '0'."* - That statement makes no sense at all. The question is about as clear as mud.

Comment: What literally doesn't make sense is PHP's meaning of "empty" :) I can accept "isset" ignoring 0, but "empty" has a very distinct meaning in the English language and "0", by definition of the word, is not empty.

Comment: Funny, that's not what the question reads as. Btw, have you tried any of the other answers?? You're leaving everyone in the dark here.

Comment: See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2220519/in-php-is-0-treated-as-empty) why `'0'` is considered empty

Comment: I'm going  to the pool now. Or better yet; the "beach".

Comment: @Fred-ii- Make some photos while you go to the beach ;-)

Comment: @CharlotteDunois or videos; they show the *real* action ;-)

Comment: @Fred-ii- Even better! Don't forget to share them with your friends (including me). ;-)

Comment: @CharlotteDunois I'll have to borrow [*this guy's face...*](https://apastorsheartdotcom.files.wordpress.com/2015/09/the-unknown-comic-2.jpg) just so I don't incriminate myself. :-) *au revoir mon amie*

Comment: possible duplicate of [In php, is 0 treated as empty?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2220519/in-php-is-0-treated-as-empty)

Comment: The other thread handles a part of the problem and has the solution as unaccepted answer, but is not technically the same question.

Comment: So why the answer then, by you http://stackoverflow.com/a/38792479/1415724 - You are only adding more confusion.

Comment: `is_numeric` does not do the job. It only works for numbers or *numeric* strings. On regular strings like `hello`, `is_numeric` will return `false`.

Comment: No, you only want your embarassing flirt attempts deleted, which have no place here. It's a different question with a different accepted answer.

Comment: again... **why the answer??** http://stackoverflow.com/a/38792479/ FFS and stop with the edits, will you?

Comment: It wasn't accepted there for a reason: It's a different question.

Comment: It doesn't matter; many were upvoted and that in its own right, constitutes as a possible duplicate. If it's a different question, then post another question based on that.

Comment: You said you were going to the pool. It seems that was a lie.

Comment: You made an answer to your own question, which isn't even a solution to your problem.

Comment: I left out some details, just like you *lol* I didn't lie. Thing is, I didn't say "when" I was going. Edit: @CharlotteDunois agreed, +1 on your comment and then some.

Comment: Don't worry, I'll delete this. Just pointing out I know why you want this deleted, and being a duplicate is not the true reason. It's always the same with Stack users who have many points. When they embarass themselves, they are looking for a reason to get the thread deleted. I'm just quickly archiving this at wayback machine.

Comment: This question should be flagged for deletion. Being a total waste of time on everyone's part.

Comment: Well, you started the chit chat here by trying to suck up to Carlotte.

Comment: *"Well, you started the chit chat here by trying to suck up to Carlotte."* - I resent that comment. Charlotte's answer was a good one and just because she probably likes me and I think she's pretty cool too, doesn't mean that I favorised her answer. I did also upvote other answers here, so don't go talking nonsense; *thank you*. Oh and why did you (suddenly) unaccept her answer; honestly now?

Answer (score 2):

What you are trying to check is string length, not "empty". This can easily be done using [strlen()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strlen.php).

```
if (isset($variable) && strlen($variable) > 0) {
    // Do something
}
```

If you want to exclude whitespace as invalid, you can add a `trim()` in there as well (generally recommended).

```
if (isset($variable) && strlen(trim($variable)) > 0 } {
    // ...
}
```

Comment: You'll get an warning with this if the variable isn't set prior to your strlen check

Comment: That's why the `isset()` call is there (I forgot to include it in my original answer).

Comment: See my answer, `strlen` is much less efficient than checking for strong equality to the `''`.   In the single case, no big deal, but if in a large loop would matter

Answer (score 2):

Yes, your way is the best (most efficient) way to:

- insure the variable has been set (so you don't get an warning checking a variable that's not been set)
- it's not the empty string `''`

  - But, could be `'0'`, `0`,`false`, `null`, or `[]` which all count as empty in php, but you wish to consider as non-empty as indicated by your OP
  - your !== will ensure only exactly the string `''` is compared (no casting/conversion)

The use of `strlen` works as well, but if you look at the opcode generated you'll see direct comparison is more 3 times computationally more efficient (assuming all operations are equally weighted, even more efficient if operations like `DO_FCALL` take significantly more cycles to execute than a basic `IS_NOT_IDENTICAL` check)

The `!== ''`version bytecode:

```
    IS_NOT_IDENTICAL                                     ~1      !0, ''
```

The `strlen() > 0` version bytecode:

```
     SEND_VAR                                                 !0
     DO_FCALL                                      1  $1      'strlen'
     IS_SMALLER                                       ~2      $1, 0
```

Comment: I'm upvoting this because of the effort and logic put into it.

Comment: @Fred-ii-  Thanks to the php `vld` library!

Comment: Good 'ol manuals, eh Ray? Well, I'm off for a dip, *ciao for now!*

Answer (score 2):

The best thing you could do, is making your own custom function. The point is to pass the variables by reference to not trigger a warning, when you pass an undefined variable. As posted as comment, I'd use something along the line `isset($variable) AND !empty($variable) AND !is_numeric($variable) AND $variable !== false` to cover all cases.

Your custom function could look like this (improved version):

```
function is_blank(&$variable) {
    return (bool) !(isset($variable) AND (!empty($variable) OR is_numeric($variable) OR $variable === false));
}
```

https://3v4l.org/ZcCDu

Comment: Charlotte, OP states in the question (which by my standards is about as clear as mud at midnight with no moon in sight): *"I'd like to do this with one check without writing a function for it..."* - If you get a downvote, I can assure you that it would not have come from me. It's not my style ;-) Good answer though.

Comment: @Fred-ii- I started writing the answer before he edited the question ;-) Also it says "*The best thing you could do,...*" If he doesn't want that, not my fault. ;-)

Comment: Yeah I know Charlotte.. *sigh*. Well the OP will have to either clarify the question, try someone's answer and/or post a comment under whatever one worked or not. I won't be adding anything else to mine. Not until I know *which animal* I'm dealing with here exactly.

Comment: @Fred-ii- Probably a *llama*, but we can't be too sure. This one doesn't wear hats!

Comment: Only the magician wears the (top) hat. The one that *the rabbit* took off with, before being chased down his (deep) hole. hehe

Comment: Requiring an extra function is indeed not what I was hoping for, but all things considered seems like the best/only way to make the code cleaner. I need to check several variables and without this it'll be an unreadable mess.

Comment: @D.Joe Yes, it's cleaner and the code gets easier to read. Unless messy code is your thing...

Comment: @D.Joe code cleanliness isn't what you asked for.  Creating a function is the worse thing you could do computationally.  You should change your post to indicate "what would make my code easist to read", but that also is subjective.  I think strait comparison to `''` is easier to understand

Comment: You are correct, should have stated that in the beginning. I do several of these checks so clean code was the main goal and I added that to the question some time ago. I didn't even consider that this isn't possible in PHP with one regular function...

Comment: Actually, I found "is_numeric", which seems better than the other suggestions? Or is there anything wrong with using that?

Comment: @CharlotteDunois I see the OP unaccepted your answer; *wow, rich*. Obviously ticked off. You know what? They should have clarified that (bad) question of theirs from the get-go. Sorry to see the green gone, but hey... they're only points. It's not like you got an arm or a hand or fingers cut off. I on the other hand (no pun intended here), would definitely miss my "fingers"; they keep me happy (it's not what you think..., I mean by playing stringed instruments) ;-)

Comment: @Fred-ii- Don't worry, I'd definitely miss my fingers too!

Answer (score 1):

*(The answer has been edited. Consult the additionals further down under "ternary operations").*

Why go through the trouble of using all that?

Just use an "not empty" `if(!empty($var)){...}`

However, if you're using this with a GET array, then yes; it would be best to use an `isset()` and `empty()` on a conditional statement.

> *I want to check if a variable has a value (including '0') and is not empty*

That to me interprets as:

*Check if a value has a value and is not empty (as you wrote) and stands to contain a 0 (zero)*.

Therefore:

`if(!empty($var) && $var='0'){...}`

---

> *I'd like to do this with one check without writing a function for it...*

Use a ternary operator then.

However *"without a function"*... right well you can't. You still need "some type of function".

About that *"ternary operator"* I mentioned above. You can reference what are called "nested ternary operations" in both these Q&A's on Stack:

- [How to concatenate multiple ternary operator in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6203026/how-to-concatenate-multiple-ternary-operator-in-php)
- [nested php ternary trouble: ternary output != if - else](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4807454/nested-php-ternary-trouble-ternary-output-if-else)

That way you won't need a custom function.

- Sidenote: I am by far not taking away or trying to take away from (Charlotte's) accepted answer (which should remain as accepted). This is just an additional method of achieving your (ultimate) goal.

Comment: `0` gets treated as empty and that's something OP doesn't want.

Comment: @CharlotteDunois I misread the question. I'll just leave the answer there. After all, downvotes are "votes" too. ;-) Just like "bad publicity is still publicity".

Comment: Are you possibly Donald Trump in disguise? ;-)

Comment: Read my comments under that question of theirs. It makes no sense at all and is so contradictory to itself and comments left, I should have just waited by the pool and watch the girls go by instead.

Comment: It's too cold here to go to the pool. :(

Comment: @CharlotteDunois It's been blistering heat here for the past 3-4 days now. I hope you get warmer weather :-) 35-38 celcius, not counting humidex. High wind factor would be a given, but then again; we wouldn't be suffering, now would we?

Comment: It was hot here in the past few days too (thank god not over 30°C), but today petrus decided to bring some rain clouds.